# Connecting to MySQL on Serverpilot via SSH & Navicat

Tags: php, mysql, ssh, server, navicat

Anyone using ServerPilot on a vps and was able to connect to the MySQL server via SSH with Navicat? On other servers/panels I do that all the time, with no problem; but it won't make the connection to a MySQL database on ServerPilot (Navicat gives a "SSH connection error; Timeout"). I'm using Navicat on my windows desktop computer, trying to connect to my remote ubuntu VPS database.

On every other server/panel that I've tried over the years, this configuration always works:

GENERAL Tab:

- *Host Name/IP Address*: 127.0.0.1 (or "localhost")
- *Port*: 3306.
- *Username*: [database username, e.g., the one assigned by ServerPilot]
- *Password* [database password, e.g., the one assigned by ServerPilot]

SSH Tab:

- *Host Name/IP Address*: [main IP of my VPS]
- *Port*: 22 (at remote VPS) [22 seems to be the correct port in ServerPilot because Putty can login on that port]
- *Username*: root [or, "serverpilot" on ServerPilot servers]
- *Password*: [the root SSH password of my VPS; or, the "serverpilot" SSH password on ServerPilot servers]

That should also work with ServerPilot according to https://serverpilot.io/community/articles/connect-to-mysql-remotely.html . But it doesn't.

I also tried separately opening an SSH tunnel with Putty per https://support.cs.wwu.edu/index.php/Tunneling_MySQL_ports_through_SSH#Tunneling_with_PuTTY_in_Windows_.28Older.29 . For databases on other servers/panels, Navicat connects to MySQL perfectly that way. But not when the database is on ServerPilot (it gives an error: "2013 - Lost connection to MySQL server during query" when "testing" the connection in Navicat).

Surely I'm not the only one who has tried connecting to MySQL on a ServerPilot server. If you got it to work, or if you know how, please explain. (BTW, phpMyAdmin works fine on ServerPilot but I find Navicat much more handy for certain tasks when programming in php.) Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, as mentioned at https://www2.navicat.com/manual/online_manual/en/navicat/mac_manual/SSHSettings.html check the "AllowTcpForwarding" setting (which should be "yes" -- otherwise, the SSH port forwarding will be disabled) in:  /etc/ssh/sshd_config . If you edited that file, then restart the SSH service. Since it is Ubuntu, it would be: "service ssh restart" (rather than "service sshd restart" as on some other flavors of linux).

If Navicat still does not connect to the remove MySQL server on the VPS connected to ServerPilot, then undo any changes you made to  /etc/ssh/sshd_config (and restart ssh). Instead of connecting with the SSH settings in Navicat, you will need to establish an SSH tunnel in PuTTY first.

**Establish a special SSH Tunnel in PuTTY**: If the first step above does not work, try this step instead.  The instructions in the cs-wwu site you cited for doing that, will not work for MySQL on Ubuntu with ServerPilot (even though it opens an SSH terminal connection that you can use for command-line actions). Instead, you need to follow the approach in the August 6, 2004 comment under https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/windows-and-ssh.html . That gives the basic idea. Here I will give the whole process in detail, step by step:

To connect Navicat to MySQL on a ServerPilot Ubuntu VSP, try these settings in PuTTY:

**1.** In the main Session screen, put this:

*Host Name (or IP Address)*: serverpilot@123.45.678.90 (put your VPS's IP address)

*Port*: 22

*Saved Sessions*: type a name such as ServerPilot-MySQL

**2.** In the Category pane on the left side, click Connection, SSH, Tunnels

In the Tunnels screen, put this:

*Source Port*: 4000 (this can be any number above 1024 that is not already being used on your Windows computer. I use 4000 because my port 3306 is currently used by my mysql on my local WAMP server on Windows).

*Destination*: localhost:3306

**3.** Click the "Add" button.  Now in the Forwarded Ports box you should see: L4000   localhost:3306

**4.** Go back to the top of the Category pane and click Session. In the Session screen, click the Save button.

**5.** Highlight the settings you just saved in the Saved Sessions box and click the Load button. Then click Open.

Now the PuTTY terminal will say:
   Using username "serverpilot".
   serverpilot@123.45.678.90's password:

**6.** Copy your "serverpilot" user's password and paste it into PuTTY by right-clicking the mouse at the prompt beside "password".

Now you have the correct kind of SSH tunnel open from PuTTY. Now use that tunnel to connect with Navicat.

**Connect with Navicat**:

Make a new Connection. In the Connection Properties, do this:

*General tab*: In the "General" tab, put this:

*Host Name/IP Address*: localhost

*Port*: 4000

*Username*: your mysql database user assigned by ServerPilot

*Username*: your mysql database password assigned by ServerPilot

In the "SSH" Tab, leave the checkmark unchecked, so Navicat will not separately attempt to connect through SSH. It will rely on PuTTY's SSH tunnel.

Go back to the General tab and click "Test connection." It should say Connection Successful. Let me know if it works for you.

Comment: The first part (about AllowTcpForwarding) did not seem to have any effect, but the second part of your answer (about PuTTY settings) worked like a charm. Thank you!